# Postfix on Ubuntu sending email from user@myhost.mydomain instead of user@mydomain.com

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

This appears to be a common issue but none of the solutions I've come across seem to be working.  I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and mailutils / postfix.
My /etc/postfix/main.cf looks like this:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
compatibility_level = 2
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mydomain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = $mydomain
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = all
```

My /etc/aliases has the following entry:

```
root: myuser@mydomain.com
```

Note I want mail to default to user@mydomain.com when I don't specify a from address.
Any suggestions are welcome!
I've tried [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/617513/postfix-sends-as-hostname-domain-com-instead-of-domain-com) and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/747051/postfix-sends-to-fqdn-hostname-instead-of-domain-name) but no success

Answer (score 2):

Postfix doesn't send mail.

It transfers mail to other servers and receives mail from other servers.

Sender is specified by the Mail User Agent, not the Mail Transfer Agent. Set whatever sender you want in whatever software you use to *send* the e-mail to Postfix for handling.

For mailutils' `mail` command, a `man mail` is suggested reading:

> from   The address (or a list of addresses) to  put  into  the  `From:'
> field of the message header. If replying to a message, these addresses are handled as if they were in  the  alternates  list. If  the machine's hostname is not valid at the Internet (for example at a dialup machine), either  this  variable or hostname have to be set to get correct Message-ID header fields.  If from contains more than one address, the sender variable must also be set.

Try `mail -a FROM:foobar@example.org barfoo@example.com` as a test of how to set the sender.

---

If you're really set on fixing this in the wrong place, you can always have a look at how [Postfix can rewrite e-mail addresses](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#masquerade). Masquerade is probably what you want:

```
masquerade_domains = example.com
```

should strip `foo.example.com` to `example.com`. But please; don't go this route. Fix the problem at the origin; the MUA that sends the e-mail to Postfix.

Comment: I was explicit about using mailutils in conjunction with postfix above.  In light of your answer, my question is: how do I have the mail bash utility send from user@mydomain.com when I don't specify a from address?

Comment: `-a FROM:foobar@example.org` will change the sender for mail in mailutils...

Comment: So mailutils cannot be configured to do that without being explicit about the from address?